# SFML Vertical Sync is not supported

Tags: c++, c++11, sfml

I trying to implement a **wator simulation** were sharks eat fishes, I want to randomly spawn sharks, the program compiles but i get "Setting Vertical Sync not supported" .

working on Ubuntu 16.04. Before i was working on something else and i got the same error but the window was displayed this is not. Any help?

**EDIT** I have fixed up the code i had one too many `{` in my loop but now i am getting a "Segmentation Fault (Core dumped)" Error i have changed my png to 8 bit but that didnt help.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>



int main()
{
  int n;
  int x;
  int y;

  sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 800), "SFML works!");
 // Set Frame Rate to 60fps
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    srand(time(0));

    sf::Texture shark;
    shark.loadFromFile("image.png");
    std::vector<sf::Sprite> Fishes(n,sf::Sprite(shark));
    for (int n = 0; n < Fishes.size(); n++){
        Fishes[n].setOrigin(15, 15);
        Fishes[n].getPosition();
        Fishes[n].setPosition(x = rand() % 790 + 10, y = rand() % -10 - 50);
    }

    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
      sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
      {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
      if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        Fishes[n].setPosition(x, y+=1);
            Fishes[n].rotate(1);

            // clear the window with black color
            window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

            // draw everything here...
            // window.draw(...);
            window.draw(Fishes[n]);

            // end the current frame
            window.display();
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your loop variable is `i` but you use `n`, a global variable. You are missing a complete loop in your rendering, just using this `n` again. I'd say you should get your logic straight first (a good idea might be to limit globals to none at all so you see what scope you are in). The v-sync is probably just a warning, your program should be fine once you fix it.

Comment: I got it working ... i had a `{` one too many

Comment: I have updated my answer with new error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still missing a loop over your fishes in your rendering loop.

Your first loop sets your loop variable `n` to the number *after* your last fish. Using that same loop variable *again* will result in undefined behavior. **Fix it**. Probably by adding another `for` loop where you use `n` the second time in your `while` rendering-loop.

Specifically, when you come to this line:

```
Fishes[n].setPosition(x, y+=1);
```

you variable `n` is **not** any kind of loop variable. Even worse it's totally random, you have not set any value. It's `int n;` from the first line after `main()`. If you delete that line (the first after main), you will see what is wrong.

Comment: could you add a code example i dont quite understand what you mean

Answer (score 2):

I would add a comment but I lack reputation. A segfault is caused writing or reading from illegal memory. In your case, I would try checking to see if your image is being loaded properly.

I would also note for loops with only one line in the body don't use just one curly bracket, use both or none.